# Head First Design Patterns vs Head First Object Oriented Analysis and Design

Tags: java, design-patterns, object-oriented-analysis

Currently I am in the process of learning Java via Head First Java and am beginning to look ahead at reading more about OOP / design patterns.

My question is which book I should pursue after Head First Java.  I am torn between Head First Design Patterns and Head First Object Oriented Analysis and Design.  No doubt, I probably should read both, but I am not exactly sure what the difference is between the two and which would be more suitable as a follow up to Head First Java.

Any suggestions or details from those who have read these would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Start with Head First Object Oriented Analysis and Design. The reason being some design patterns require a good knowledge of object oriented programming beforehand.

Now you are stepping into development territory its not only important to read but to also work through your own examples. For example trying to write a piece of software to do something is far more productive than reading 300 pages from a book. Learning about software is very practical so its important to apply what you are learning.

Generally a lot of books rehash the same principles, but if you like the style of the Head First books then by all means read them. If your at all interested in the Java programming language I would recommend a book called [Effective Java by Joshua Bloch.](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/)

Comment: I do already have a project that I am going to be working on, because I do learn best by doing.  In addition I will be pursuing other Java books, because the Head First series is obviously just a starting point.  Thank you for your feedback!

Comment: @IOInterrupt No problem. My point was that you shouldn't get too caught up in learning everything. No developer knows absolutely everything. Instead just enjoy what your doing and use the books as reference. Seems like you already are applying what your learning.

Comment: @adamjmarkham I also have finished Head First Java book, and i have heard that Effective Java is a very advanced book, should i consider it? or it will not be understandable to me as i have only read Head First Java.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I love those books, so great choise :-) "Head First Design Patterns" speaks only about design patterns, "Head First Object Oriented Analysis and Design" contains a lot more like requirements engineering, testing etc. So if you want to learn OOP, then I would suggest to choose the design patterns book first and then the other one.